# access denied for python manage.py syncdb

Tags: python, django

I'm following a Django tutorial and I bought a 1 month subscription to webfaction.com to practice some web programming.

The tutorial is telling me to type `python manage.py syncdb` at the application directory, which for me is: D:\Users\yangs\Downloads\Django-1.3.1\Django-1.3.1\build\scripts-2.7\mysite

But I get an error message that reads:

```
_msql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'flammenmeer_'@'c-68-38-119-33.hsd1.nj.comcast.net' (using password: YES)")

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',   # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'flammenmeer_',                 # Or path to database filw
        'USER': '',                             # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'my_password',              # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': 'flammenmeer.webfactional.com', # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                             # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
        'USER': 'flammenmeer_',
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error message? Thank you in advance!

edit: I also tried:

- web329.webfaction.com for host
- I made a new database without the underscore named flammenmeer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So all webfaction databases will be named [account name]_aname and the whole thing has to be under 16 characters.  So if your username is "flammenmeer" you already have 12 characters used including the underscore.  So for your example, let's pretend you create a database in the admin panel named "test", your database name will be flammenmeer_test.  Also, your username is the same as the database name.  And lastly, you don't need to define the host, the localhost default will suffice.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'flammenmeer_test',
        'USER': 'flammenmeer_test',
        'PASSWORD': 'blahblahblah',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

---

**Edited to provide info on how to run django on webfaction, not local computer**

You can't access a webfaction database externally unless you pay for a static IP address.  It sounds like you're running the Django tutorial on your local computer, not on Webfaction (based on the location of your project being a D drive).

1. Make sure you've created a database in the Webfaction control panel with whatever 4 character name after "flammenmeer_" that you want, an example would be "flammenmeer_test"
2. [Download Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) (the very first "Putty.exe" link on that page)
3. In Putty, connect to flammenmeer@[machine name].webfaction.com (machine name would be something like "web312" and will be the same machine that you created the database on.  Your final product might look something like flammenmeer@web312.webfaction.com
4. Install Django on your webfaction account

   - Type "easy_insall-2.7 django"
5. Create a directory for your django scripts

   - Type "mkdir scripts"
   - Type "cd scripts"
6. Create a new Django Project

   - Type "python2.7 ~/lib/python2.7/django/bin/django-admin.py startproject ruhemeer"
   - Type "cd ruhemeer"
7. Edit your settings (you are going to want to learn [VIM](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/vimcheat.html)

   - Type "vim settings.py"
   - Hit the letter "i" to enter edit/insert mode
   - Use the arrow keys to navigate to the database settings and modify the settings
   - Hit "Esc" to exit edit/insert mode
   - Type ":wq [enter]"
8. Carry on with the Django Tutorial :)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried making a database with the name, "Flammenmeer_test" but I'm still getting the same error message.  How does manage.py know where my application is hosted?

Comment: Ok, So I did some digging and found out I can use the SSH? to access my data.  I got to the directory named "myproject" and I want to access settings.py so I can edit it with all the information.  How do I go about opening the file to edit?

Answer (score 0):

Because, the information to connect the database are not correct. just check it on time more.

Are you sure there is an underscore at the end of the username, it seems a little bit weird

Comment: I'm sure for everything except HOST.  I made a database named flammenmeer_ and it said that they created a user for the database named, "flammenmeer_". So i'm guessing it's the same for the database name and user name.  Is the port necessary for something like this?

Comment: Ok, But have you grant access to the database to the user?

Comment: yes, after I create a database it says: MySQL database "flammenmeer_" has been created. User "flammenmeer_" has been created(default password "blahblahblah" and has permissions to work on the new database

Comment: i created a new database without the underscore and i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: you have to access your database by localhost, because most of the time, if your database is host on the same server that the django one, so try localhost, or 127.0.0.1

Comment: localhost brings back: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)") and so does 127.0.01. I also tried web329.webfaction.com.

Comment: Ok, and in fact the host was good otherwise it couldn't  have verify that you were a correct user, sorry for that! So for me, the password is wrong or the user, but i can be mistaken

Comment: Thank you for helping but I'm still not sure what's wrong lol. I triple chcked the password/databasename/username

Comment: But maybe the password has been badly recorded in the db can you login into your server or phpMyadmin or a stuff like this?

Comment: yes I can login to my control panel and phpmyadmin without a problem.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing an entire step.  If I leave the host blank, how does it even know which site the database is hosted on?

Comment: with the same user and psswd? This way i don't understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access your webfaction database server from your Windows computer, which is why you are running into these problems.

To practice with django you do not need a database server or web server.

First, install django. Since you are on Windows, use [this link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#django) to download a Windows installer for django.

Install it just like you would any other Windows program.

Now, to start your project:

1. Open the command prompt. Type the windows key + R to bring up the Run prompt, type `cmd` and hit enter.
2. Create a directory where you want to work. For example, `mkdir c:\work`
3. Change into that directory `cd work` so your prompt is `C:\work>`
4. Type `python C:\Python27\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject myproject`

This will create the `myproject` directory under `work`.

Edit `settings.py` file and make the following change to `DATABASES`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'test.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

Working in Windows it helps to have a IDE. [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) is my favorite. It is a Python IDE for Windows that includes excellent support for django. You can download a free trial.

Once you have it installed, simply open the directory `myproject` from the IDE.